# How can I replace text inside the parentheses using re.sub()

Tags: python, regex

For example I have a string like this:

```
'(1) item 1. \n(2) item 2'
```

I should end up with this:

```
'(x) item 1. \n(x) item 2'
```

how can I only match the text inside the parentheses, and replace them? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You tagged the question with regex, but have you actually tried to write a regex for this yet? What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: What kind of strings can appear inside parentheses? The regex you need depends a lot on what sort of input you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [3]: import re
In [4]: re.sub("\([^)]*","(x",'(1) item 1. \n(2) item 2')
Out[4]: '(x) item 1. \n(x) item 2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the brackets:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = '(1) item 1. \n(2) item 2'

In [3]: re.sub(r'\(\d+\)', '(x)', s)
Out[3]: '(x) item 1. \n(x) item 2'
```

You need to escape them because they have special meaning in the regex context (create a numbered group).

Answer (score 0):

```
"\([^)]+\)"
```

Will match anything in parenthesis, so you could do

```
"(1) item 1. \n(2) item 2".gsub(/\([^)]+\)/, "(x)")
```

in ruby.

Edit: Fixing formatting so the escapes are not lost...